# How to set User's Consent notGranted by default on Flutter HERE SDK?

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/navigation_app

As in this repo here I know HERE SDK needs user permission for Android devices. But I don't want to show it to users. Can I set the content engine as not granted by default when app starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConsentEngine` is only necessary when you want to use the `LocationEngine`. By default, it is not granted. So, there's nothing to do and you can continue to use other parts of your application until you need to grant consent.

This [location guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/get-locations.html#handle-the-users-consent-whether-to-gather-information) explains this in greater details.